# Как использовать переменную конфига в качестве string?

Tags: mysql, golang

У меня есть конфиг в котором лежат все данные о БД и мне нужно эти данные импортировать. Но я не могу импортировать переменную конфига, которая по сути и является `string` строкой в методе открытия `БД MySQL`!

```
db, err = sql.Open("mysql", Config.MYSQL.Data)
```

Config.yml:

```
MYSQL:
  data: root@/formm
  columns: api
```

Полный код:

```
import ( 
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/jinzhu/configor"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func DBPrimary() {

    var Config = struct {

        MYSQL struct {
            Data string `yaml:data`
            Columns string `yaml:columns`
        } `yaml:"FTP"`

    }{} 

    configor.Load(&Config, "config.yml")

    var db *sql.DB 
    var err error

    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", Config.MYSQL.Data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("OK Connect to DB")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Ok test a connection")
    }

    stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO (?) VALUES (?,?,?)")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Succ insert a value")
    }

    rows, err := stmt.Exec("api", , "succ3", "succ2", "succ1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)

    } else {
        fmt.Println("Succ insert smtm value!")
    }

    ttt, err := db.Exec("CREATE TABLE primary ( db_id integer, db_text text, db_single varchar(255) )")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Succ create table!")
    }

    fmt.Println(rows, ttt)

}
```

Лог: `2017/12/08 11:52:34 Error 1046: No database selected`

Данные на БД только из конфига импортируются, другими способами они не могут быть импортированы. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Выведи в лог эту `Config.MYSQL.Data` и покажи что в ней.

Comment: @IvanBlack 2017/12/08 11:52:34 Error 1046: No database selected

Comment: Перед `sql.Open(...)` добавь строку `log.Println("CONFIG:", Config.MYSQL.Data)`. Похоже что у тебя конфиг кривой вот и всё. `No database selected` значит, что нужно выбрать базу данных. Должно быть что-то типа `user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/hello`, где `hello` - это имя базы данных. Которого, вероятно, и нет. А оно должно быть.

Comment: Судя по всему конфиг кривой или загружается криво. Нужно увидеть это значение, чтоб ответить что-то конкретное.

Comment: @IvanBlack действительно, вывод: { } но почему конфиг кривой? в data лежит root@/formm должно все нормально импортироваться.

Comment: Для того чтоб ответить на этот вопрос, нужно увидеть этот файл и знать что это за `configor`.

Comment: @IvanBlack обновил вопрос. configor это модуль для работы с конфигами

Answer (score 0):

Дело в

```yaml
MYSQL:
  data: root@/formm
  columns: api
```

и

```go
} `yaml:"FTP"`
```

Должно быть

```yaml
---
FTP:
  data: root@/formm
  columns: api
```

с тремя чёрточками или без, разницы нет. Или измените имя поля структуры на FTP.